# Can we pass custom data from email script to notification template?

Tags: javascript, servicenow

I've a Notification (sysevent_email_action) that will be using a Email Script (sys_script_email). The notification is defined on "Global" table and under "Send when", it's set as "Event is fired". The event contains parm1 data which will be processed inside the email script.

I was wondering if from inside the email script, I can define a variable and then use that variable inside the notification template?

So, the flow is:

(a) Event `abc` is fired with `event.parm1` containing some data

(b) Notification gets executed when `abc` is triggered

(c) Notification calls an email script

(d) Inside the email script, `abc's` parm1 is accessed and a variable is defined. Let's say something like this:

```
    (function runMailScript(current, template,
 email, email_action, event) {
    
             var eventData = JSON.parse(event.parm1);
             // do something with eventData
             // then define a variable
             var data_to_use_in_template = eventData.foo;
             var data_to_use_in_template2 = eventData.bar;
    
    })(current, template, email, email_action, event);
```

(e) In Notification template, somehow use `data_to_use_in_template` and `data_to_use_in_template2` that got populated with data in email script.

```
Hi,

Thank you for responding back. Here are details of the order:

Foo: ${data_to_use_in_template}

Bar: ${data_to_use_in_template2}
```